# Is Azure data factory and Azure Synapse billing for pipelines are same?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, estimation

If we want to calculate the Estimated cost for Azure synapse, Is it similar to how the calculation happens on ADF? (I understand the prices may differ)
Scenario that a Pipeline runs for 10 mins ever hour (8 hours)
Pipeline has a dataflow activity which takes 10 mins to execute.
Trigger counts to 1 activity.

Uses Basic VCores.
Different pricing scales may apply for ADF and Synapse. But the method is the question.
Appreciate the support from members.

I tried all examples in ADF given by Microsoft. I want to know the that is it same for Azure Synapse as well? Please refer to the links that shows samples for Azure synapse pipeline cost estimation.